# window.DeviceOrientationEvent is undefined in Safari on iOS (React web-app)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-360

I have a React app running on a server that uses some React 360 components. One of the components has a button with an onClick event which points to a method `askPermission()`. I'm trying to have the method ask permission to use the DeviceOrientationEvent as described in [this article](https://dev.to/li/how-to-requestpermission-for-devicemotion-and-deviceorientation-events-in-ios-13-46g2). Unfortunately `window.DeviceOrientationEvent` is undefined in this method, which makes it impossible to request permission. I'm outputting window, and it is defined:

```js
askPermission = function () {
  console.log('asking permission') //outputted
  console.log(window) //object
  console.log(window.DeviceOrientationEvent) //undefined
  ...
}

render() {
  return (
      ...
      <VrButton onClick={askPermission}>
      ...
      </VrButton>
      ...
  );
}
```

Is there something specific to Safari (on iOS 13.x) that makes `DeviceOrientationEvent` unavailable? What could be the reason and how could I access this property?

EDIT: I tried the same on Chrome (on Android), and it also doesn't have the DeviceOrientationEvent property on window.

Comment: Hi Yuri, I don't know if you had resolved the problem, but I got the same problem. I'm thinking that it is necessary to call that function from a native module, not from a component. I'll update my comment after some tries.

Comment: @GiuseppePennisi I haven't fixed this in the end and turned to a different library to run VR, would still be curious to if you figured it out!